# True or False: If $$ is square and |$\det()|=1$, then $^{−1}$ has integer entries.

Tags: linear-algebra

Thanks for the feedback on my most recent question. So it is not explicitly stated that A has integer matrices. Therefore I conclude that it is false. Can you please help me think of a counterexample? I am having a hard time doing so. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

For each $\theta$, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks. What a great example I failed to see

Comment: Happy to help ^_^ if this answered your question, you should mark it as accepted so other users know how to spend their time

Answer (score 3):

How about
$$\pmatrix{1&x\\0&1}$$
where $x$ is a non-integer?

But if $\det A=\pm1$ then $A^{-1}$ has integer entries iff $A$ does (user Cramer's rule).

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Even in $2 \times 2$ matrices, there are four entries.  The determinant is one equation, so you still have three degrees of freedom.  Pick any three entries as you wish, making sure that one of them is not an integer.  Then pick the fourth to make the determinant $1$.  Subtracting $1$ doesn't change whether the entries are integers.  Done.

Comment: Sometimes I overthink problems and fail to see the mechanics of some problems. Thanks a lot